# XSS interceptor for Jax-rs using Apache CXF

Tags: jax-rs, cxf, xss, interceptor

I am working on XSS interceptor task using CXF. As per project dependencies I cannot use Jersey. And I cannot see any way to change form data (form parameters) from request using interceptors or filters. 
I found from docs that we cannot modify request parameters (excluding query parameters) using cxf although jersey provides a way to modify these parameters.

But in Interceptors also I am not able to see any way to modify form parameters. I can see many examples to modify headers / query parameters. But cannot see any example to modify request parameters. Can anyone provide some help and give me sample code example for this.

Right now I am checking with ReaderInterceptor. But it is also not invoking as the way Interceptors gets invoked. Please let me know if you have any idea about that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define an interceptor to capture the inbound messages before they are processed by your bussiness service, extract the form parameters, pass the XSS filter and update params or abort processing depending on your needs.

**Interceptors**

This is a basic example using CXF `AbstractPhaseInterceptor`

```
public class XSSInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

    public XSSInterceptor () {
        super(Phase.INVOKE);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {

        // filter only application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        String contentType = (String)message.get(Message.CONTENT_TYPE);
        if (MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED.equals(contentType)){ /

            // message parts
            List list = message.getContent(List.class); 
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size();i++){

                //get the parameter map
                MultivaluedMap<String, String> params = (MultivaluedMap<String, String> )list.get(i);
                for(String param: params.keySet()){
                    List<String> values = params.get(param);

                    //XSS filter here. Update the value list if needed or abort the request
                    List<String> updatedValues = xssFilter(values);
                    params.put(param, updatedValues);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void handleFault(Message messageParam) {
    }
 }
```

**CXF configuration**

```
<bean id="xssInterceptor" class="XSSInterceptor" />
<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="xssInterceptor"/>
   </cxf:inInterceptors>
</cxf:bus>
```

This configuration will apply to service like this

```
@POST
@Path("/form")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
public Response form(MultivaluedMap<String, String> params) throws WebApplicationException;
```

***RequestContextFilter**

Alternatively you can use RequestContextFilter

```
 public class CustomRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
   public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) {
    Message m = JAXRSUtils.getCurrentMessage(); 
    //XSS filter here. In the same way the above intercerceptor
    // finally use context.abortWith(Response) if you need to block the request
```

Spring config

```
<bean id="customRequestFilter" class="com.CustomRequestFilter" />

 <!-- Add filters to provider zone in JAX-RS server-->
 <bean id="myRestServer" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean" lazy-init="false" init-method="create">
    ...
     <property name="providers">
         <list>
              <ref bean="customRequestFilter" />
         </list>
     </property>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help XSSInterceptor is working fine, but we cannot update form parameters using CustomRequestFilter. I tried it but it failed.

Comment: hi @pedrofb, can you please help me, if we change the MediaType of our rest service from APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED to Application_json. Because in my case our UI will send only Application_json request and it is failing in that case. What changes I need to do for this

Comment: With `application/json` you have to deal with the incoming stream, not parameters. Get it with `message.getContent(InputStream.class)`, consume and process the string data, and set the new content with `message.getExchange().setContent(analyzedStream)`

Answer (score 0):

@PreMatching
public class XSSInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor {

```
private XSSRequestWrapper xssRequestWrapper;

public XSSInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.POST_LOGICAL);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) message.get("HTTP.REQUEST");
    xssRequestWrapper = new XSSRequestWrapper(httpRequest);

    // filter only application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    String contentType = (String) message.get(Message.CONTENT_TYPE);
    if (MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED.equalsIgnoreCase(contentType)
            || MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.equalsIgnoreCase(contentType)) {
        // message parts
        List list = message.getContent(List.class);
        String jsonString = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            jsonString = list.get(i).toString();
        }

        Response response = Response.status(Response.Status.ACCEPTED)
                .entity(xssRequestWrapper.stripXSS(jsonString)).build();

        message.getExchange().put(Response.class, response);
    }
}
```

}

This interceptor will work for the following rest api operations: - 
 @POST
    @Path("details2")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response getPersonalInfoDetails2(String jsonString) throws DataNotFoundException;